# Using "Due to" in this sentence

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, adverbs

I think in the sentence below, I shouldn't use "due to" as I start it with "One of the main reasons" but I would like to use "due to" because the reason is just a simple phrase. How can I restate this sentence with "due to"

I may say "this is due to ...", but it is just one reason not the only reason.

> As a matter of fact, many native speakers of English have problems with spelling correctly. One of the main reasons for this is **due to** the complex orthography of English.

**Update**: I myself find this alternative

> Part of the problem is **due to** the complex orthography of English.

Comment: Side note: You either have [problems + verb] or [problems with + noun]. So it should be either "... have problems spelling correctly." or "... have problems with the correct spelling."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

> One of the main reasons for this is due to the complex orthography of English.

You are basically saying the same thing *twice*, roughly "this is because".

So either you write

> [One of the reasons is] the complex orthography.

*or*

> [This is due to] the complex orthography.

Now you want to explicitly say that the orthography is but one reason, so you have to "tone down" the due to by some restricting expression, like

> [This is *partly* due to]...
>   [This is *mainly* due to]...
>   ....

---

Overlap with your edit:

Yes, your sugestion works too.

Comment: Thank you, *This is mainly due to* is what I was looking for.